# How to access inner AsyncTask class from another class and retrieve its result

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

newbie here, I am trying to call `AsyncTask` from inner `AsyncTask` as shown below but it's not working. Can somebody point me in the right direction? When I call the method `setCrowdSubtitle` from `card1` it's okay, but not when trying to set it from `AsyncTask` class.

```
class Card extends CardBase {

public void setCrowdTitle(String cTitle) {
    CardHeader header = new CardHeader(getContext());
    header.setTitle(cTitle);
    header.setButtonExpandVisible(true);
    addCardHeader(header);
}

public class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        return GET(urls[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        }
}
}

class Activity {

private class LoaderAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,  ArrayList<Card>> {
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Card> doInBackground(Void... params) {

        if (isAdded()) {
            ArrayList<Card> cards = initcrowdCard();
            return cards;
        } else
            return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Card> cards) {

        onRefreshComplete(cards);
}

private ArrayList<Card> initcrowdCard() {

    ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();

    Card card1 = new Card(this.getActivity(), R.layout.crowd_card);
    card1.setCrowdSubtitle("Url");
    cards.add(card1);

    Card card2 = new Card(this.getActivity(), R.layout.crowd_card);
    card2.new HttpAsyncTask() {
        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(String picUrl) {
            card2.setCrowdSubtitle(picUrl);
        }
    }.execute(phpScript);
   cards.add(card2);
}
}
```

Comment: What is the line of code that's not working ?

Comment: Where is `setCrowdSubtitle()` defined in class `Card` ?

Comment: @Talha Edited the code to include the `setCrowdSubtitle()` method. @NAIT The piece of code not working is `Card card2 = new Card(this.getActivity(), R.layout.crowd_card);
    card2.new HttpAsyncTask() {
        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(String picUrl) {
            card2.setCrowdSubtitle(picUrl);
        }
    }.execute(phpScript);
   cards.add(card2);`

Comment: Why are you overriding `onPostExecute() `  from outside? I dont see any specific reason? You can call `setCrowdSubtitle` in `onPostExecute() ` of  `HttpAsyncTask` , it may raise error where you may need to declare `setCrowdSubtitle` as **final**.

Comment: Also `card2.new HttpAsyncTask() {...` does this line gives error or behaves unexpectedly ? You specified 2 lines, these can be different errors, also post your stack trace (error logs).